# Pytest and concurrent.futures interacting strangely

Tags: python, pytest, concurrent.futures

I am using `pytest` to test my project, and I am using `concurrent.futures` to add parallelism to some of my algorithms. When I use `pytest` without the parallelized code, the tests complete as expected. When I run the parallelized code directly (without `pytest`), the code executes as expected. However, when I try to run pytest on parallelized code, some lines importing my project modules, such as

```
import tools_2d.classes
```

throw the exception

```
AttributeError: module 'tools_2d' has no attribute 'classes'
```

Thus, `pytest` and `concurrent.futures` seem to be working when used independently, but throw exceptions when used together. It seems that the workers spawned by multiprocessing cannot find my project modules when invoked by pytest. What am I doing wrong?

I am using python 3.9 on Windows. My project has the following structure:

```
repo
|-- tools_2d
|   |-- algorithms.py
|   |-- classes.py
|   |-- drawing.py
|   `-- utils.py
|-- algorithms
|   |-- line.py
|   `-- region.py
|-- tests
|   `-- test_algorithms.py
|-- main.py
|-- storage.py
|-- requirements.txt
`-- ...
```

Comment: The issue isn't about `pytest`,  it's about where you're running `pytest` from. Try to create a `__init__.py` file inside the folders to be able to import `tools_2d.classes`.

Comment: In which directory should I add them? I thought there is no need to explicitly add `__init__.py` on python versions 3.3+, since implicit namespace packages would be implied instead.

Comment: Depends on how you use it. Add the init file in every folder that contains code and the root folder, see if it solves it.

Comment: I have tried adding `__init__.py` to all directories containing code (and various combinations), and none of it seems to work.

Comment: Import from repo, repo.tools2d.classes